# Why doesn't Excel show the full array when I type a structured reference into a cell?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, structured-references

I'm pretty new to Excel, so please forgive me.

I'm watching a tutorial right now and when he types a structured reference into an empty cell, i.e.

```
=Tracking[Category]
```

it spits our the entire referenced array.

When I do it, only the respective row value appears and I have to drag down the autofill-handlebar to see the rest of the array. It is vital for the spreadsheet to work that this command gives me the whole array at once. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does he do that in a [Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)?

Comment: You probably don't have Office 365.